# VS Unit Test Doesn't See Expected and Actual Results as Equal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tdd

We’re moving to a TDD style of development at work in the near future, so I’m trying out the VS Unit Test that comes with VS 2013 (which is what we use at work).  I’m attempting to use TDD to write a class that will find Kaprekar’s constant.  I’m at a point in my development that I have a test that submits a valid number and I expect to have a list containing one element returned.  That element will consist of a 3 cell array.  The three cells will contain the original number, a number that has the digits in descending order, and a number that has the digits in ascending order.  My debugging code shows that I get my expected results back, but Unit Test says I don’t.  What do I need to do to have Unit Test see the expected and actual results as equal?  Here’s an **abridged** version of my code.

## Unit Test Code:

```
namespace KaprekarsConstantTest
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Kaprekar k;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        k = new Kaprekar();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FirstRow()
    {
        int[] row = new int[3];
        row[0] = 5324;
        row[1] = 5423;
        row[2] = 2345;
        List<int[]> expected = new List<int[]>();
        expected.Add(row);
        List<int[]> actual = k.Generate(5324);
        int[] rslt = actual[0];
        int[] expct = expected[0];
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual,
            "\nExpect: " + expct[0].ToString() + "; " + expct[1].ToString() + "; " + expct[2].ToString() +
            "\nActual: " + rslt[0].ToString() + "; " + rslt[1].ToString() + "; " + rslt[2].ToString() + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

## Application Code

```
namespace KaprekarsConstant
{
public class Kaprekar
{
    public List<int[]> Generate(params int[] orgNum)
    {
        List<int[]> rtnVal = new List<int[]>();
        int num = orgNum[0];
        string digits = num.ToString();
        int[] row = new int[3];
        row[0] = num;
        List<int> lstDigits = new List<int>();
        string snglNum = String.Empty;
        for (int ndx = 0; ndx < 4; ndx++)
        {
            snglNum = digits[ndx].ToString();
            lstDigits.Add(int.Parse(snglNum));
        }
        lstDigits.Sort();
        string dNum = String.Empty;
        for (int ndx = 3; ndx > -1; ndx--)
            dNum = dNum + lstDigits[ndx].ToString();
        row[1] = int.Parse(dNum);
        string aNum = String.Empty;
        for (int ndx = 0; ndx < 4; ndx++)
            aNum = aNum + lstDigits[ndx].ToString();
        row[2] = int.Parse(aNum);
        rtnVal.Add(row);
        return rtnVal;
    }
  }
}
```

## Test Result

**Test Name:**  FirstRow

**Test FullName:**  KaprekarsConstantTest.UnitTest1.FirstRow

**Test Source:***   …\Projects\C_Sharp\KaprekarsConstant\KaprekarsConstantTest\UnitTest1.cs : line 51

**Test Outcome:**   Failed

**Test Duration:**  0:00:00.0033773

**Result Message:** CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed.

Expect: 5324; 5423; 2345

Actual: 5324; 5432; 2345

(Element at index 0 do not match.)

**Result StackTrace:**  at KaprekarsConstantTest.UnitTest1.FirstRow() in …\Projects\C_Sharp\KaprekarsConstant\KaprekarsConstantTest\UnitTest1.cs:line 61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why this test is failing:

- The first element (element 0) of each List is an array of three elements. They don't actually match - the second elements of the first element are 54**23** and 54**32**. Even if you fix this, it will still fail because...
- Secondly, you'll need to tell .NET to do a structural comparison of the elements of the list, it is doing an object reference comparison by default - i.e. reference equality on each int[] array.

Change your collection assert as follows:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
    expected, actual, 
    System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralComparer,
    "\nExpect: " + ... // omitted for brevity
);
```

and the test will pass.

If you just compare arrays, the test framework *will* do a piecemeal comparison, so this test, for example, will pass:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WillCompareByElement()
{
    var x = new[] { 3, 2 };
    var y = new[] { 3, 2 };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(x, y);
}
```

You might get clearer test failure messages looping over each element of the list and comparing that way.

Also, you could consider using a decent assertion library like Shouldly. Then you can write:

```
expected.ShouldBe(actual);
```

And get output like:

```
Message: Test method SOTestEquals.UnitTest1.SecondRow threw exception: 
Shouldly.ShouldAssertException: [[5324, 5423, 2345]]
    should be
[[5324, 5432, 2345]]
    but was not
    difference
[*[5324, 5423, 2345]*]
```

Saving you writing the custom output.

Comment: Thanks James.  I'll look into Shouldly.  At work there is some discussion of using NUnit because of the syntax compatibility with JUnit.  (There is considerable development in Java.)

Comment: Shouldly (like most assertion libraries) complements testing libraries. i.e. You can (and should!) use NUnit and Shouldly together. Other assertion libraries are available - Fluent Assertions is another popular one. All are aimed at enriching the assertion experience within a given testing framework.